# Custom audio player issues

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/CSS">
            #custom{
                font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 16px;
            max-width: 650px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 8px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            padding-left: 12px;
            padding-right: 12px;
        }
        img{
            margin-top: 3px;
            float: left;
        }
        #bar, #currentTime, #duration, #skip{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #currentTime, #duration, #skip{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin-top: 3px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        #bar{
            margin-top: 10px;
            height: 14px;
            width: 400px;
            background: lightgrey;
            border-radius: 50px;
            margin-left: 9px;

        }
        #slider{
            height: 14px;
            width: 15px;
            background: black;
            border-radius: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onLoad="count()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var track = 0;
        function count(){       
            var music = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            var duration = music.duration;
            var durationInMins = Math.floor(duration/60);
            var durationInSecs = Math.floor(duration-(durationInMins*60));
                if(durationInSecs < 10){
                    var durationInSecs = "0" + durationInSecs;
                }
                if(durationInMins < 10){
                    var durationInMins = "0" + durationInMins;
                }
            document.getElementById("duration").innerHTML = durationInMins + ":" + durationInSecs;
            var timer = setInterval( 
                function(){
                    var music = document.getElementById("myAudio");
                    var currentTime = music.currentTime;
                    if(currentTime > 60){
                        var min = Math.floor(currentTime/60);
                        var sec = Math.floor(currentTime-(min*60)); 
                    }else{
                        var min = "0";
                        var sec = Math.floor(music.currentTime);                        }
                    if(sec < 10){
                        var sec = "0" + sec;
                    }
                    if(min < 10){
                        var min = "0" + min;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;                     var percent = 100 * (music.currentTime/duration) - 2;
                    document.getElementById("slider").style.marginLeft=percent + "%";
                }
            , 1000);
            }
        function toggleP(){
            var music = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            if(music.paused == true){
                music.play();
            }else if(music.paused == false){
                music.pause();
            }
        }
        function skip(){
            var trackList = ["http://fidelak.free.fr/reprises/The%20Doors%20-%20People%20are%20Strange.mp3", "http://mp3light.net/assets/songs/14000-14999/14781-december-1963-oh-what-a-night-four-seasons--1411568407.mp3"];
            if(go == "back"){
                track = track - 1;
            }
            if(go == "forward"){
                track = track + 1;
            }
            var aa = clearInterval("timer");
            var music = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            music.pause();
            music.src=trackList[track];
            music.load();
            var a = setTimeout(function(){music.play(); count();} , 6000);
        }
    </script>
    <audio id="myAudio" src="http://fidelak.free.fr/reprises/The%20Doors%20-%20People%20are%20Strange.mp3">
    </audio>
    <br>
    <div id="custom">
            <img onClick="toggleP()" src="img/media-play-pause-resume.png" height="30px"/>
        <p id="currentTime">00:00</p>
        <div id="bar">
            <div id="slider"></div>
        </div>
        <p id="duration">00:00</p>
        <p id="skip"><strong><a onClick="go = 'back'; skip()"><<</a> <a onClick="go = 'forward'; skip()">>></a><strong></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Could anyone tell me why the song duration slider jumps forwards and backwards after you skip to the second song? And why the duration bar cannot be moved down with margin-top without moving everything with it. I just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... are you allowed to use jQuery? I'm asking cause that way you can do in a couple of lines a really nice player with draggable slider etc...

Comment: No, the point of this was to make one in pure JavaScript.

Comment: Damian, here's your code: http://jsbin.com/kayesu/1/edit?html,css,js,output . Sorry but all I can see is 14 errors in JS, `NaN` errors, unescaped `<` and `>` in HTML etc etc. Nothing jumps back and forth. It plays one song , than it simply halts miserably on any other interaction with your code.

Comment: you're welcome! Happy coding. If there's someting you don't understand from my examples (I tried to keep it "simple/short"...) please, feel free to ask.

Comment: P.S: if you'd like to see an example usign jQuery and jQuery UI for the drag stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753756/how-to-change-the-html5-audio-volume-or-track-position-with-a-slider

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Note: I revisited the old code and figured out why it jumped. After skipping the track, the slider was displaying the times for both songs (It was still running for the old song). Adding clearInterval fixed it. Though as noted, the old code was poorly written and won't be used. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/bajeli/4/edit)***

**Don't** use **inline JS** in your HTML! Makes code hard to debug. Keep your logic away from your presentation/template.

To start from, how variables work?
Once you set a `var`, there's no need to instantiate the same var again using `var` inside your code. Simply use/modify it. So once you set at the top

```
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Helps get easily an element

var el_music    = el("myAudio"), // see?
    el_trackInfo= el("trackInfo"),
    el_duration = el("duration"),
    el_currTime = el("currentTime"),
    el_slider   = el("slider"),
    el_prev     = el("prev"), // assign ID to your prev/next buttons!
    el_next     = el("next"),
    el_togg     = el("toggle"),
    currentTime,    
    trackList = [],
    track = -1,    // Later we'll set it to 0 index triggering auto start
    totTrack = trackList.length;
```

...you're good to go. No more `var` statements further in your code.

You probably want to show some more info to the user.
A good way to store your data is to create Objects with the desired properties:

```
trackList = [
  {
    artist : "The Doors",
    fileName : "People Are Strange",
    file : "http://fidelak.free.fr/reprises/The%20Doors%20-%20People%20are%20Strange.mp3"
  },
  {
    artist : "ACDC",
    fileName : "Back In Black",
    file : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg"
  },
  {
    artist : "Four Seasons",
    fileName : "Oh What A Night",
    file : "http://mp3light.net/assets/songs/14000-14999/14781-december-1963-oh-what-a-night-four-seasons--1411568407.mp3"
  }
]
```

now you can not only get the desired audio path, but also show the user more info about a track.

**Don't Repeat Yourself**. Calculating times all over the place makes your code not modular but messy.  Instead create a function that'll help you `return` the desired formatted time:

```
function getTime(t) { // `t` is some time value
  var m = ~~(t / 60),
      s = ~~(t % 60);
  return (m<10?"0"+m:m) +':'+ (s<10?"0"+s:s); // returns i.e: "01:25"
}
```

Create a progress function like:

```
function progress() {
  el_currTime.innerHTML = getTime(el_music.currentTime); // see how our getTime fn is used?
  el_duration.innerHTML = getTime(el_music.duration);
  el_slider.style.marginLeft = Math.floor(100/el_music.duration*el_music.currentTime) + "%";
}
```

than a play/pause one:

```
function playPause(){
  var isPaused = el_music.paused;
  el_music[isPaused ? "play" : "pause"]();
  el_togg.innerHTML = isPaused ? "&#10074;&#10074;" : "&#9658;" ;
}
```

for the PREV/NEXT, assign IDs to your buttons `id="prev"` and `id="next"` and again create a function that will handle both click cases:

```
function skip(){ // This gets triggered by both prev / next buttons.
  track = this.id==="next" ? ++track : --track; // Next clicked' increment, else decr.
  track = track < 0 ? totTrack-1 : track%totTrack; // Allows you to loop infinitely the index
  var trackToPlay = trackList[ track ]; // Get the Track Object "{}"
  el_trackInfo.innerHTML = trackToPlay.artist+' '+trackToPlay.fileName;
  el_music.src = trackToPlay.file;
  el_music.addEventListener('canplaythrough', el_music.play);
}
```

Believe it or not - **you're done!**
Having all those nifty functions in place, what you need now is some event listeners:

```
el_prev.addEventListener("click", skip);
el_next.addEventListener("click", skip);
el_togg.addEventListener("click", playPause);
el_music.addEventListener("timeupdate", progress);
el_music.addEventListener("ended", playPause);

el_next.click(); // Auto Start playing!
```

Now you probably wonder where's your interval 1000 function gone? It's simply handled by `el_music.addEventListener("timeupdate", progress);`.

Comment: Nice walk through, I would just make the `el_music.addEventListener('canplaythrough', el_music.play);` out of the `skip`function or at least call `el_music.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', el_music.play);` to avoid adding useless event handlers.

Comment: Very helpful code, but could you tell me what was making the slider jump back and forth?

Comment: with all the bugs and issues you had I'd also like to know that

Answer (score 1):

The skipping may be caused by the fact that the interval is never stopped, and is still running for the previous song.