# Add volume bar to HTML 5 audio player

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm new at JavaScript and trying to add a volume bar to my HTML 5 audio player but I'm not having great success. This is what I have so far:

JS:

```
var VolumeSlider = player.querySelector('.volume-bar');
VolumeSlider.addEventListener('input', function(){
audio.volume=this.value;
step=.01;
min=0;
max=1;
value=1;
}, false);
```

PHP:

```
<div class="volume-bar"></div>
```

The above doesn't do anything with adding a volume bar. Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/bgaOGE

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your volume input from a div to input type range.

```js
(function(){

  var pcastPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('.pcast-player');
  var speeds = [ 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3 ]

  for(i=0;i<pcastPlayers.length;i++) {
    var player = pcastPlayers[i];
    var audio = player.querySelector('audio');
    var play = player.querySelector('.pcast-play');
    var pause = player.querySelector('.pcast-pause');
    var rewind = player.querySelector('.pcast-rewind');
    var forward = player.querySelector('.pcast-forward');
    var progress = player.querySelector('.pcast-progress');
    var speed = player.querySelector('.pcast-speed');
    var mute = player.querySelector('.pcast-mute');
    var currentTime = player.querySelector('.pcast-currenttime');
    var duration = player.querySelector('.pcast-duration');
    var VolumeSlider = player.querySelector('.volume-bar');

    var currentSpeedIdx = 0;

    pause.style.display = 'none';

    var toHHMMSS = function ( totalsecs ) {
        var sec_num = parseInt(totalsecs, 10); // don't forget the second param
        var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours; }
        if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
        if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}

        var time = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
        return time;
    }

    function onloadedmetadata(){
      progress.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(audio.duration));
      duration.textContent  = toHHMMSS(audio.duration);
    }
    if(audio.duration){
      onloadedmetadata();
    }else{  audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', onloadedmetadata);
    }
    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
      progress.setAttribute('value', audio.currentTime);
      currentTime.textContent  = toHHMMSS(audio.currentTime);
    });

    play.addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.style.display = 'none';
      pause.style.display = 'inline-block';
      pause.focus();
      audio.play();
    }, false);

    pause.addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.style.display = 'none';
      play.style.display = 'inline-block';
      play.focus();
      audio.pause();
    }, false);

    rewind.addEventListener('click', function(){
      audio.currentTime -= 15;
    }, false);

    forward.addEventListener('click', function(){
      audio.currentTime += 15;
    }, false);

    progress.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      audio.currentTime = Math.floor(audio.duration) * (e.offsetX / e.target.offsetWidth);
    }, false);

    speed.addEventListener('click', function(){
      currentSpeedIdx = currentSpeedIdx + 1 < speeds.length ? currentSpeedIdx + 1 : 0;
      audio.playbackRate = speeds[currentSpeedIdx];
      this.textContent  = speeds[currentSpeedIdx] + 'x';
      return true;
    }, false);

    VolumeSlider.addEventListener('input', function(){
    audio.volume= parseInt(this.value)/10;
    step=.01;
    min=0;
    max=1;
    value=1;
    }, false);

    mute.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if(audio.muted) {
        audio.muted = false;
   this.querySelector('span').innerHTML = 'Mute'; 
      } else {
        audio.muted = true;     this.querySelector('span').innerHTML = 'Unmute';   
      }
    }, false);
  }
})(this);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Audio</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="pcast-player">
<div class="pcast-player-controls">
 <div class="player-left">
  <button class="pcast-rewind"><div class="rewind-bttn"><span class="text-left">-15</span></div></button>
  <button class="pcast-play"><span class="text">Play</span></button>
    <button class="pcast-pause"><span class="text">Pause</span></button>
  <button class="pcast-forward"><div class="forward-bttn"><span class="text-right">+15</span></div></button>
 </div>
 <div class="player-progress">
  <div class="player-bar">
   <progress class="pcast-progress" value="0"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="player-time">
   <span class="pcast-currenttime pcast-time">00:00</span>/
   <span class="pcast-duration pcast-time">00:00</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="player-right">
  <button class="pcast-speed speed-button">1x</button>
    <button class="pcast-mute">
  <span class="text">Mute</span></button>
     <input class="volume-bar" type="range" min="0" max="10">
 </div>
</div>
<audio src="http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/302696028-scott-johnson-27-filmsack-critcondition.mp3"></audio>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I made some other minor alteration to your code. Make changes on it based on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, this is greatly appreciated! One question: does the volume bar have to be `input` and not a div?

Comment: Yes, it have to be an input, otherwise you won't get any value to set.

Comment: What about security? This is an input and i'm opening myself up for problems?

Comment: If you are not saving any changes to database then you don't have worry much about security, and there are always measures you can take sanitize form inputs. Alternatively you could use buttons instead of input, here is a jsbin https://jsbin.com/xexifav/edit?html,js,output with buttons for volume increase and decrease, personally I like range, because it's more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks again. I know that other players are able to do a volume bar in a div (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753756/how-to-change-the-html5-audio-volume-or-track-position-with-a-slider?noredirect=1&lq=1) but since I have zero knowledge of jquery, this will do. Thanks again for the help.