# Set Default Volume in script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that loops music on load, but it is too loud. I have a slider bar to change the music volume, but how would I default it to 25% of the slider?

[WEBSITE](http://prova.city)

```
<audio id=music loop autoplay src="peep.mp3">
  <p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
<input id="vol-control" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)" onchange="SetVolume(this.value)"></input>

<script>
    function SetVolume(val)
    {
        var player = document.getElementById('music');
        console.log('Before: ' + player.volume);
        player.volume = val / 100;
        console.log('After: ' + player.volume);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: BTW, unless you're building a music website I'd highly discourage you to **autoplay** audio on a website. You don't like random song playing on the web neither do others. It's easier to close the tab (to not ruin my favorite youtube song) than searching for an inexistent mute button... Not to talk about people with scarse connections or on some low mobile plan.

Comment: `SetVolume(25);` outside; and `document.getElementById("vol-control").value=val` inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a script that set the volume:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("music");
audio.volume = 0.25;
```

Comment: Setting volume at 0.25 but leaving a volume handler at *N%* is yuck UI...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `audio` tags, just get the DOM Node in Javascript and manipulate the `volume` property

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
// Getting
console.log(volume); // 1
// Setting
audio.volume = 0.5; // Reduce the Volume by Half
```

The number that you set should be in the range `0.0` to `1.0`, where `0.0` is the quietest and `1.0` is the loudest.

Answer (score 0):

- `input` is a Void element and as such does not needs a closing `</input>`
- You're using `max`, `min`, well, use also `value`.
- Avoid using inline JavaScript. Keep you logic away from your markup.
- init your function like `setVolume()`
- use camelCase `setVolume` instead of PascalCase `SetVolume`, since it's a *normal* function, not a Method, Class or constructor...

```js
const audio = document.getElementById('audio'),
      input = document.getElementById('volume'),
      setVolume = () => audio.volume = input.value / 100;

input.addEventListener("input", setVolume);
setVolume();
```

```html
<audio id=audio loop autoplay src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg">Audio is not supported on your browser. Update it.</audio>

<input id=volume type=range min=0 max=100 value=25 step=1>
```

I think you'd also like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20753900/383904).